# Can't connect website to database on amazon web services

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I've just loaded my mvc.net 3 website up onto a micro instance on Amazon Web Services and put the database up there on a RDS as well. I can connect to the database via AWS Explorer in VS2010 just fine but when I add the connection string to my `web.config` it times out trying to access the database. Is there something else I need to do?

The web site loads fine, it just times out when accessing the DB.

Sorry if this is a but vague, the whole AWS thing is new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a permissions issue and like the other poster said you need to grant access to your web server.  The best practice for EC2 instances to gain access to RDS instance is to add the EC2 security group permission in the RDS security group.  This way if you switch EC2 instances or do something else that causes your internal IP to change you are unaffected.

To do this in the AWS Explorer double click on the RDS security group to launch the RDS security group view with the group selected.  In the details screen click "Add Permission" button then select your EC2 security group and push okay.

Comment: Norm, thanks for the reply. Your suggestion was correct, I can now connect to my db and now have a code first error to look into next. Thanks for you help.

Comment: had similar issue, the problem was that the inbound IP was set to some predefined IP, I needed to set it to my IP

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the security group for your RDS instance isn't allow incoming connections from your webserver. Get the internal IP of your webserver and add it the security group for your RDS instance (All this can be done in the AWS console). That should at least clear up the connectivity issue.